# Errors about compareTo & TreeSet (Java)

Tags: java

So I've been trying to figure out how Collections work in Java (by looking at an old project we did in uni) but I keep getting some errors I cannot fix, it has something to do with the Comparable function

This is my first class:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Client  {

private int hour;
private int minute;
private int min_per_stay;
private double price;

public Client(int h, int m, int mps, double p)
{
    this.hour = h;
    this.minute = m;
    this.min_per_stay = mps;
    this.price = p;
}

public void SetHour(int h)
{
    this.hour = h;
}

public void SetMin(int m)
{
    this.minute = m;
}

public void SetMinPStay(int mps)
{
    this.min_per_stay = mps;
}

public void SetPrice(double p)
{
    this.price = p;
}

public int GetHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public int GetMin()
{
    return minute;
}

public int GetMinPStay()
{
    return min_per_stay;
}

public double GetPrice()
{
    return price;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Hours: " + this.hour + 
            " Minutes: " + this.minute +
            " Minutes per stay:" + this.min_per_stay +
            " Price: " + this.price + "\n";

}

public boolean equals(Client c) {
    return (this.hour == ((Client)c).GetHour() && this.minute == ((Client)c).GetMin());
}

public int CompareTo(Client c)
{
    if (this.hour<((Client)c).hour) return -1;
    if(this.minute<((Client)c).minute) return -1;
    if (this.hour>((Client)c).hour) return 1; 
    if(this.minute>((Client)c).minute) return 1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

And my collection:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientCollection{

private SortedSet<Client> oClient = new TreeSet<Client>();

public ClientCollection()
{

}

public ClientCollection(String FileName)
{
    try
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(FileName));
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        oClient.add(new Client(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),
                sc.nextInt(),sc.nextDouble()));
    }
    sc.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
}

public void addClient(Client c)
{
    oClient.add(c);
}

public  List<Client> reverseList()
{
    List<Client> oList1 = new ArrayList<Client>(oClient);
    List<Client> oList2 = new ArrayList<Client>();

    for(ListIterator<Client> it = (oList1.listIterator(oClient.size())); it.hasPrevious(); )
    {
        Client res = it.previous();
        oList2.add(res);
    }
    return oList2;
}

public void printColl()
{
    System.out.println(oClient.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ClientCollection oc = new ClientCollection("test.txt");
    oc.printColl();

    oc.reverseList();
    oc.printColl();
}

}
```

and the errors I get are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Client cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at ClientCollection.<init>(ClientCollection.java:20)
    at ClientCollection.main(ClientCollection.java:56)
```

i'll be really happy if someone explains the errors to me, im still kinda new at this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Client` class doesn't implement the `Comparable<Client>` interface (i.e. `Client` doesn't have a natural ordering).

Therefore, in order for it to be used as an element of a `TreeSet`, you must pass to the `TreeSet<Client>` constructor a `Comparator<Client>`, which specifies the ordering of `Client` elements.

Failing to do so results in `ClassCastException`, since the `TreeSet` class (or rather the `TreeMap` class that is uses behind the scenes) assumes that if you didn't supply a `Comparator` in the constructor, this means that your `Client` implements `Comparable`.

EDIT: Since you have a `CompareTo` method in the `Client` class, it looks like you intended to implement `Comparable`.

Change:

```
public class Client
```

to:

```
public class Client implements Comparable<Client>
```

and change:

```
public int CompareTo(Client c)
```

to:

```
public int compareTo(Client c)
```

You might want to modify the logic of your `compareTo` method, though.

Comment: Actually, Client has a `CompareTo` method - it's just capitalized wrong, and the OP forgot to implement Comparable. It's a much smaller change for the OP to fix that than to implement a Comparator.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I didn't notice that. I just saw that Client doesn't have an `implements Comparable<Client>` clause.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the implementation of the comparison is wrong: comparing hours `<`, then minutes `<`, then hours `>`, then hours `>` will give the wrong result. Do all of the hours comparisons first, then all of the minutes comparisons.

Comment: @AndyTurner yep, that's what the last line of my answer is referring to. Perhaps I should have included some details.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Eran wrote, you need to write method names starting with a lower case letter. You can see that StackOverflow's formatter gets confused by it. It will also confuse anybody having to maintain your code.

Your `compareTo` method should look like this:

```
public int compareTo(final Client c)
{
    final int diffHours = this.hour - c.hour;
    if (diffHours == 0) {
        return this.minute - c.minute;
    } else {
        return diffHours;
    }
}
```

The casts are unnecessary, since the `c` parameter is already of type `Client`.