# TreeSet instance in Set reference variable

Tags: java, set, treeset

For the code:

```
Set<Phone> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add(new Phone("Harry"));
```

I get error:

> Phone cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable

Why Phone has to implement Comparable if reference variable is type `Set`?

If the reference variable was `TreeSet`, then of course, class `Phone` must implement `Comparable`.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the reference variable is. Your actual object is `TreeSet`

Comment: Set is an interface, TreeSet is the implementation. So implementation is what’s used.

Comment: This Q&A is closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966013/errors-about-compareto-treeset-java.  The difference is that in the other Q the OP has attempted to implement a `compareTo` but has 1) not declared his class to `implement Comparable<T>` and 2) gotten the name of the method wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [Javadoc for `TreeSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet--):

> Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements. **All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable interface.**

The elements have to be somehow comparable because `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet`. Note that `Set`s are not necessarily unordered, merely that the `Set` interface does not specify the ordering. Implementing classes are allowed to define an ordering of the elements.

If you want to insert non-Comparable instances into the comparator (or use a non-natural ordering), you must invoke the constructor with an explicit comparator.

```
Set <Phone> set = new TreeSet<>(someComparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the reference type is `Set`, the actual implementation is still `TreeSet` so `TreeSet.add()` method is called. The parameter check happens in the runtime, when `ThreeSet.add()` is invoked and you get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable
```

Comment: oh i see. method "add" i used from TreeSet and that method requires "compare" method

Comment: @mislav23 - Not exactly.  1) the method required in this case is `compareTo` (not `compare`), **and** 2) the class has to `implement` the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The actual type only matters. It's a `TreeSet`, which is based on a `TreeMap`, which works with `Comparable`s unless another comparator is specified.

You could define a comparator based, for instance, on a `Phone` property. It would obviate the need to implement `Comparable` for `Phone`.

```
Set<Phone> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Phone::getModel));
```